# How to ignore typescript errors in jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, expo

how to ignore some typescript errors when running the tests with jest ?

I have tried to use `// @ts-ignore` comment, but still not working for jest.

I am using `jest-expo` which internally uses `jest@25.0.2`

```
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
   header: {
     // here is the typescript error
     position: "sticky"
   }
})
```

here `position: "sticky"` is not defined in the type of `Stylesheet` and I want to suppress this error

Comment: Please provide examples of the type of error that you widh to suppress.

Comment: maybe some ts-jest configuration work for me

Comment: Yes, i got the same issue, although I comment my function with // @ts-ignore ( since it's coming from outer API, so i cant "define" that function, either type it ), jest still typing it... comes to think of it, I debug it, and it's coming from "chunk" files, there are no comments assigned, maybe that's why it's not ignoring, and generating this bug while testing.

Answer (score 0):

Call this utility function anywhere you want within your test file.

```
/**
 * Embeds code that will never run within a callback. Useful for
 * testing expected type errors.
 * @param description Description of the code that will never run
 * @param callback Callback that will never run
 */
export function ignore(_description: string, _code: () => void) {}
```

I like to embed it within the relevant `describe`. For example:

```
describe("insertions", () => {

  // ...

  ignore("insertOne() type errors", () => {
    // @ts-expect-error - inserted object must have all required columns
    userTable.insertOne({});
    // @ts-expect-error - inserted object must have all required columns
    userTable.insertOne({ email: "xyz@pdq.xyz" });
    // @ts-expect-error - returning argument can't be a string
    userTable.insertOne(USERS[0], "id");
    // @ts-expect-error - returning argument can't be a string
    userTable.insertOne(USERS[0], "*");
    // @ts-expect-error - returning arguments must be valid column names
    userTable.insertOne(USERS[0], [""]);
    // @ts-expect-error - returning arguments must be valid column names
    userTable.insertOne(USERS[0], ["notThere"]);
    // @ts-expect-error - returning arguments must be valid column names
    userTable.insertOne(USERS[0], ["notThere", "*"]);
  });
});
```

The type "tests" are done by the compiler at compile time.

You may need to add this linter rule to get `ignore()` itself to compile:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off'
```